# oAuth 2 token Request Invalid

Tags: rest-api, api, integration, oauth2, oauth

I have created a connected app in salesforce so that the external system can connect to our org.

They are using oauth2 so i have set it up accordingly and shared the client key and client secret.

```
https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But while I am trying to access the same from postman tool, I am getting 'grant type not supported '

is it client credentials is not supported in salesforce to get the token .

Also if I change to password , it says

```
https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9lcxCTdG2Vbs7E5OwQecRVkliAxcnCh4dEoJtZfP1P.5Wb5n8IFFP69b.SJ2faiw4_jh1&client_secret=370769049890&username=username@test.com&password=237857235237645


{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "authentication failure"
}
```

I tried with security token as well no luck.

But I have to use client_credentials only as grant type as the external system wanted that.

Can any1 help !
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exception in first type because `grant_type=client_credentials` is not a correct value. Salesforce only support `authorization_code` or `password`.

In your case you need the `authorization_code`. First you need to get the authorization code and then using that code in your request you will get access token.

This is how your sample request will look like with code

```
POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.salesforce.com 
grant_type=authorization_code&code=aPrxsmIEeqM9PiQroGEWx1UiMQd95_5JUZ
VEhsOFhS8EVvbfYBBJli2W5fn3zbo.8hojaNW_1g%3D%3D&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNI
NVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82HnFVVX19KY1uA5mu0QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCs
cA9GE&client_secret=1955279925675241571&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Fcode_callback.jsp
```

[Understanding the Web Server OAuth Authentication Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm)

In the username-password flow you might need to append your security token to get the Accesstoken from user.

[Understanding the Username-Password OAuth Authentication Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm)

Comment: Does it mean client credentials is not supported in salesforce oAuth2.0 so I can't use that ? I have to use auth code and password flow only here

Comment: @AbhikDey Yes you are correct.

Comment: I just tried with password as grant type : - https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=rQeHvzSc6lzs7E5OwQecRVkliAxcnCh4dEoJtZfP1P.5Wb5n8IFFP69b.SJ2faiw4_jh1&client_secret=3709049890&username=XXXXXXXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXXXXXhDCGAcGt9ZJ8S and still it says {
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "authentication failure"
} tried with security token and without token....is their any way I can see some goood logs what causing the issue

Comment: @AbhikDey You are getting status code. Try to google that in Salesforce docs.

Answer (score 0):

@Abhik Dey use like this `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrC5JDWLwQDrf6JviH8U3N60lZZtkwLkcMLcbfGbmuKJa_LqEpfumGXRoBiqexD.ot.rk84Z
&client_secret=6234465375317883048&username=test123@gmail.com&password=test@505&Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded` its working for me use POST method and replace with your credentials and check it
[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried excatly the same one you posted just replacing the necessary details but still i get this {
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "authentication failure"
} I tried with security token as well and also in the app i made it as Relax IP restrcitions but still no luck

Comment: In postman if i use the option "send client credential in body" , i gt the token response but if i use "send as basic auth" i get the invalid grant error. I attached the postmanscreenshot

Comment: @Abhik Dey  iam getting see my screen shot then you get some idea

Comment: No luck https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PVJpwnCgaxuMQViaHG3su3ICJsFXLu1w/view?usp=sharing

Comment: may be what the hell I am missing...it is so simple but eating my brain like anything

Comment: @Abhik Dey dont pass the parametes in headers   click on param  then pass it there then check it

Comment: I tried putting it in the param key value as well, no luck..Not sure what is the issue but I noticed one thing, if I put all these parameters in the request body , then i get the access token from postman. So, I beleive we should be adding the grant type and other param details in the body only, and the end point url should be on the request Url i.e till token https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token